# Insert Haml file name in Haml document output

Tags: ruby, haml

How do I dynamically insert the name of a Haml file in a Haml document?

Something like:

```
%b =insert_file_name
```

in a file named foo.haml should output

```
<b>foo.haml</b>
```

Comment: Write a helper to return the filename. I seriously doubt one exists, as HAML is compiled from an in-memory string.

Comment: Depending on how you’re sing it, `__FILE__` should work. When the string is compiled a value to use for the filename can be passed in, and if it has you can use `__FILE__` to get it. The `haml` command line tool does this correctly, as does Tilt (used by Sinatra) and I think Rails does too.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be nice if HAML had its equivalent of `$0` or `__FILE__` to retrieve the current template, but I haven't seen anything like that in the documentation. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
require 'haml'
```

First, create a variable or a constant holding the name of the template you want to use:

```
HAML_FILE = 'test.haml'
```

Set variables, and do what you need, then read the template, and pass it to HAML for rendering:

```
haml_template = File.read(HAML_FILE)
engine = Haml::Engine.new(haml_template)
puts engine.render
```

This is the output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>test.haml</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the template I used:

```
%html
  %body
    %p= HAML_FILE
```

Comment: I wanted to do it dynamically through introspection.

Comment: I didn't see anything exposed in Haml's gem docs that lets you do that. You might be able to do it by browsing the source-code and adding a method, or by overriding something, but, as is, it doesn't look like there's a way to have it tell you what the current template is. I'd recommend asking the developer's directly.